# SUMIFS starting with

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a SUMIF formula, where I am trying to SUM all items that are starting with one of the following numbers:
4
5
6
7

So I wrote it down like this:

`=SUMIFS('Data-NEW'!Q:Q;'Data-NEW'!S:S;"4*";'Data-NEW'!S:S;"5*";'Data-NEW'!S:S;"6*";'Data-NEW'!S:S;"7*")`

However in some cases this formula does not work (strangely).

Is the syntax correct in this case?

P.S. Maybe it is evaluating this formula in a way, that a cell has to start with all of the mentioned above (not just like one of them?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the multiple if statements or conditions you are checking within the SUMIF function are treated as AND conditions as opposed to OR.  In order for it to be treated as an OR you will need to do a SUMIF for you 4* check and add if to a sumif for you 5* check which you add to your next number and so on.

```
=SUMIF('Data-NEW'!S:S;"4*";'Data-NEW'!Q:Q)+SUMIF('Data-NEW'!S:S;"5*";'Data-NEW'!Q:Q)+SUMIF('Data-NEW'!S:S;"6*";'Data-NEW'!Q:Q)+SUMIF('Data-NEW'!S:S;"7*";'Data-NEW'!Q:Q)
```

Comment: Thought so! Thank you

Comment: Array formula `=SUM(SUMIF('Data-NEW'!S:S;{"4*";"5*";"6*";"7*"};'Data-NEW'!Q:Q))`

Comment: @ScottCraner I think you hit comment instead of answer on that one!  its worthy of its own answer.  I would not have thought of that.  I abore/loath CSE formulas so you can take the credit for it instead 8)

Answer (score 0):

SUMIFS uses AND, meaning you would need S to be 4* AND S to be 5*, which obviously isn't so. Instead use 4 SUMIFS.